# OAuthException: Invalid response from google

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-cloud-shell

So I am running my Flask application from the google cloud shell. In this app the user needs to login with their google account. I installed all the required libraries using the cloud shell.

When I run the app in the cloud shell, after choosing the google account I want to log into my app with, this error comes up

```
flask_oauth.OAuthException
OAuthException: Invalid response from google
```

Everything works fine if I run it from local host.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

PS: This is the code

Flask.py:

```
import logging
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, session, make_response
from flask_oauth import OAuth
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError
import MySQLdb
import os
import json

Client_Id = my client id
Client_Secret = my client secret
Redirect_URI = '/callback'

SECRET_KEY = 'funny cat'
DEBUG = True

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = DEBUG
app.secret_key = SECRET_KEY
oauth = OAuth()

google = oauth.remote_app('google', base_url='https://www.google.com/accounts/', authorize_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth', request_token_url=None, request_token_params={'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile', 'response_type': 'code'}, access_token_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', access_token_method='POST', access_token_params={'grant_type': 'authorization_code'}, consumer_key=Client_Id, consumer_secret=Client_Secret)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("webpage1.html")                  

@app.route('/login',methods=['post','get'])
def login():
    access_token = session.get('access_token')
    if access_token is None:
        return redirect(url_for('direct'))

    access_token = access_token[0]
    headers = {'Authorization': 'OAuth '+access_token}
    req = Request('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo',
                  None, headers)
    try:
        res = urlopen(req)
    except URLError, e:
        if e.code == 401:
            session.pop('access_token', None)
            return redirect(url_for('direct'))
        return res.read()
    data = json.load(res)
    return render_template("webpage2.html", data = data)

@app.route('/direct')
def direct():
    callback=url_for('authorized', _external=True)
    return google.authorize(callback=callback)

@app.route(Redirect_URI)
@google.authorized_handler
def authorized(resp):
    access_token = resp['access_token']
    session['access_token'] = access_token, ''
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('access_token', None)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

@google.tokengetter
def get_access_token():
    return session.get('access_token')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

My credentials in the API are

```
Authorized JavaScript origins : https://5000-dot-4778310-dot-devshell.appspot.com   
Authorized redirect URIs : https://5000-dot-4778310-dot-devshell.appspot.com/callback
```

Why is the project name different for the same client id and client secret?

Comment: What do you have configured in `Client ID for Web application` in the Google Cloud Console? The `Authorized JavaScript origins` and `Authorized redirect URIs` must be correct. This means both the URL and port number.

Comment: Those are alright. I am being asked to select the google account I want to use to login with. I am also giving the password. The problem seems to occur after callback. If `Authorized JavaScript origins` and `Authorized redirect URIs` were the problem I would not have been directed to the google accounts page in the first place.

Comment: You redirect url is not correct. As I mentioned, you must have the port correct. Your Flask server is configured for HTTP on port 8080. Your redirect URI is configured for HTTPS and port 443. They don't match. Your Flask server is not running HTTPS which is mandatory except for localhost mode. Your Flask server is listening on localhost which means it will never receive a callback. However, if you are actually running this in a localhost mode, then your redirect URI should be http://localhost:8080.

Comment: If you are running in localhost mode, then your web browser must also run withing the same machine (vm). Cloud Shell does not have a web browser.

Comment: Where should I make changes to run my flask server HTTPS?

Comment: Where did you get the URLs for your Cloud Shell? I am curious. Remeber they will change every time you launch Cloud Shell.

Comment: You will not be able to setup HTTS for Flask running on Cloud Shell. In order to serve HTTPS traffic, you will need an SSL certificate. You don't have one for the Cloud Shell domain.

Comment: Create a new question about SSL setup for Flask and I will answer that.

Comment: Everytime I run python Flask.py in the cloud shell they give a link in the shell. This is the URI I am directed to everytime I click on it. And it remains same everytime. It does not change

Comment: It will change after 60 minutes of being idle. Cloud Shell is then shutdown and discarded. A new VM is launched the next time you connect. The data that you store relative to your home directory persists but nothing else. This also means that your Python libraries must be installed relative to your home directory.

Comment: Creating a new question

Comment: I can post that question after 90 minutes

Comment: Please do not modify an existing question. Create a new question.

Comment: The reason for the difference is that you do not have a verified domain name associated with your Client ID.

Comment: But the name I gave to my project with the above client ID and secret is Sample GCP

Comment: When running in localhost mode, which does not require a verified domain, your app name is displayed. When running in callback mode, you need a verified domain so Google Account is displaying the URL instead of the app name.

Comment: Your original question has been answered. Mark this as complete and create new questions.

Answer (score 2):

This question is really how to setup Google OAuth 2.0 using Flask / Python running inside a Google Cloud Shell VM.

Google OAuth 2.0 authorization can be peformed in two modes: localhost mode and callback mode.

**Localhost mode**

This requires that the entire authentication process be performed within the same machine with a locally running web server. The web browser that connects to Google Domain must also be running inside the same machine. The browser cannot be running on a different machine (or VM). Since Cloud Shell does not have a web browser, this mode is not possible.

**Callback mode**

This requires that the web server is running with TLS configured. Google OAuth 2.0 only supports a callback url to an HTTPS endpoint. This also requires a verified domain name and an SSL certificate. Since you neither control the Cloud Shell domain name, nor have the private key for the certificate, setting up TLS is not possible.

Therefore, the answer to this question is that it is not possible to setup a server process running in Cloud Shell to handle Google OAuth 2.0 authentication.

In this user's case, the callback URL did not match how his Flask web server was configured. In this situation, correctly configuring the callback URL is not possible.